# C#: how to check and display the content of a folder?

Tags: c#

I'm not sure whether this topics has been disscussed before or not, but I'm not sure the exact word to search for it. What method/class should I use?

The program has 3 buttons: **1) for folder browsing, 2) scan for the selected folder content, and  3) open the file.** When user browse the selected folder**(1)**, user click scan button to scan from the first file until the last available files and listed it text box**(2)** and from that user can decide whether to open the files or not**(3)**.

Here are what have I done so far (no 1 and 3):

```
//For browse.
private void browse2()
{
    if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
        this.txtDest.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
     }
}

//For opening folder.
private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Process.Start(txtDest.Text);
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select one file/folder");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to replicate the functionality of the OpenFileDialog? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287592(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Why don't you use the FolderBrowser of .NET to browse te folders?

Comment: This is a very strange question, certainly if you see one of your previous questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420408/c-how-to-browse-for-folder

Comment: Dear Byron Ross, Yes it similar but i want to list out the content first. then after that, the selection of the file is done by the btnOpen().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to just **open a file** you can directly use an [Open File Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984392%28VS.71%29.aspx).

If you need to **display the contents of a directory** you can use the [Directory Info Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Well my example is a WPF app that adds files/ folders in a directory to a treeview, but you should get the general idea:

**Note:** Code was written for a training exercise, and therefore only goes 3 levels deep, as a proof of concept kind of thing

```
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DriveInfo di in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
            {
                TreeViewItem drive = new TreeViewItem();
                drive.Header = di.Name;
                treeView1.Items.Add(drive);

                DirectoryInfo folders = new DirectoryInfo(di.Name);

                // The depth count means that it only goes 3 levels deep, to make it quick to load
                GetFoldersAndFiles(drive, folders, 3);
            }
        }

        private static void GetFoldersAndFiles(TreeViewItem parent, DirectoryInfo folders, int depth)
        {        
            if ((depth > 0)
            {
                foreach (DirectoryInfo dirI in folders.GetDirectories())
                {
                    TreeViewItem dir = new TreeViewItem();
                    dir.Header = dirI.Name;
                    parent.Items.Add(dir);

                    GetFoldersAndFiles(dir, dirI, depth - 1);
                }

                foreach (FileInfo fileI in folders.GetFiles())
                {
                    TreeViewItem file = new TreeViewItem();
                    file.Header = fileI.Name;
                    parent.Items.Add(file);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Be ware that a solution that calls itself does work, but if you check enough folders you will get a stackoverflow ( No pun intended ).