# Standard drive/network tree view in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a control that I can use that operates like windows explorer for selecting drives and network resources or does this functionality have to be built from scratch?  Specifically I am talking about the left panel of explorer where you can select the different drives on the PC or the network.

I went through the list of the default controls and I don't see one offhand.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this related to wpf or winforms? You should tag it as such and include that information in your question.

Comment: `OpenFileDialog`, `SaveFileDialog`, `FolderBrowserDialog` and `Shell.BrowseForFolder`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420408/how-to-browse-for-folder

Comment: What you are looking for is called `TreeView` control.

Comment: @MikeNakis I am familiar with TreeView.  But that, alone, will not show drives and network structures.

Comment: You could probably find a dozen implementations on the internet.  Nothing provided built in — you will have to create it yourself.